# Correct use of 'with' or 'at' when talking about percentages?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, prepositions

I'm writing the following sentence:

> Women lead uptake at XX%.

But a friend is saying that it should be written:

> Women lead uptake with XX%.

Which one is correct?

Comment: I barely understand either without some context. I guess this is a headline: the grammar of headlines is different from English grammar (hardly any articles are needed, for example). I think both are equally unclear, partly because it gives no hint what the percentage is *of*: of people, of women, of potential taker-uppers, of instances of whatever it is that is being taken up?

Comment: I agree, I'd like some context. For example: why is there no article before *uptake*?

Comment: English is not my native language actually so I'm struggling a bit with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use 'with' if you are reporting the percentage as a fraction of the whole.  Use 'at' if you are reporting the percentage as a target or score.

"William won the school election, with 62% of the votes."

"The polls indicated that William's approval rating was at 73%."

Answer (score 0):

I would say 'with' is strictly correct: you are essentially shortening:

> Women lead uptake with XX% *of the total*

That doesn't make sense with at:

> Women lead uptake at XX% of the total

Comment: I think the "at" form is shortening "Women lead uptake *because their uptake is are at* XX% *of whatever it is* - like saying "Bill is the tallest at 7 feet"; clearly "with" in the last sentence would have a very different meaning :-)

Comment: @Psmears: Perhaps we could analyse it as "being at [the point/level of]"? It is then a non-defining attribute.

Answer (score 0):

"with" means "By the means of"
"at" means "in or near the location of"
i would use "by".buy an economics newspaper tomorrow. You can see a whole page of examples.

Comment: Without context we can't really know, but "lead by 10%" would have a very different meaning from "lead with 10%": the first would mean that they're 10% ahead; the second would mean that they have 10% (of whatever it is), but we don't know whether the runner-up has 0%, 9.99%, or anything in between :)

Comment: can you please show me an example of "...with (percentage)". Maybe some article from a native writer. thanks

Comment: @Fiona Cheung: http://blogs.abc.net.au/antonygreen/2011/03/how-av-builds-a-majority-for-a-candidate.html - first sentence.

Comment: Antony Green’s blog post has moved [here](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2011-03-06/how-av-builds-a-majority-for-a-candidate/9389696).  Also it’s in the Wayback Machine [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160323004135/http://blogs.abc.net.au/antonygreen/2011/03/how-av-builds-a-majority-for-a-candidate.html).