# Difference between "with" and "at" when it comes to percentages

Tags: prepositions, percentages

I have a problem in using "at" and "with" in describing graphs and percentages. I have read many samples in different books, but I am not quite sure that I can use them properly. I even find a similar topic on this [other ELU question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9526/correct-use-of-with-or-at-when-talking-about-percentages) but it did not help either. So I provide here some examples from different books so that you can answer them:

1. > Shopping came next at 10%, although this was much less popular than socializing, at 20%.

Can we use "with" instead of "at" in the above sentence?

2. > Socializing was next at 20%, which was twice as popular as shopping, with 10%.

Can we replace "at" with "with" in the above sentence, and vice versa?

3. > Both alcohol and drug sales peaked in 1980 with figures of $186 billion and $102 billion respectively.

Can we change it to:

> Both alcohol and drug sales peaked in 1980 at $186 billion and $102 billion respectively.

4. > Indonesia was responsible for about one third of rice production, at just over 46 million tonnes.

Can we change it to "with"?

5. > No change was seen in jogging at 31% in the two older age groups for women.

Can we change it to "with"?

Comment: No, it's "at," not "with".

Comment: Why would you want to replace *at*? Why do you need *with*? Is there a reason?

Comment: @Kris: you are very dogmatic but surely both are very commonly used. Isn't it just a matter of style?

Comment: @JeremyC It's a matter of grammar.

Comment: @bookmanu It's a duplicate, but the example in the linked question isn't very clear.

Comment: @bookmanu I already mentioned the [https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9526/correct-use-of-with-or-at-when-talking-about-percentages], but the answers weren't clear.

Comment: @Kris I don't want to replace "at", I want to know that in these particular context that I mentioned are they interchangeable? If not, why? Because there are some overlaps here.

Comment: @JoMakintash  Oops! I didn't click on your reference, sorry

Comment: @Lawrence Yes, quite right. I didn't click on OP's link

Comment: @JoMakintash Of course, they are **not** interchangeable as do not mean the same thing.

Comment: For clarification, in this example: it isn't correct to change "with" with "at"?
Socializing was next at 20%, which was twice as popular as shopping, with 10%.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Prepositions are notoriously hard for everyone. In many cases (I could have said "with many such things"), it's a matter of style and common usage, more than following a formula to get the exact right word.

But your intuition is correct, in many sentences either "at" or "with" could be used

When you quote a fact, number or thing as part of a series, using "at" is common and simple. "At" places a thing within a context. The word "with" could also be used, but with different phrasing.

"The most popular activities were golfing, at 25 percent, walking, at 20 percent, and swimming, at 18 percent."

If I really want to use "with," I can rephrase it:

"The most popular activities were golfing, with 25 percent of individuals favoring that activity; walking, with a 20-percent favorite percentage; and swimming, with 18 percent of respondents calling it their favorite leisure activity."